# iOS and Objective-C: most of CPU time is spent in [NSObject release] and [NSObject retain] but class method is not doing any memory operations

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, profiling, instruments

An image processing applications runs fast on the simulator, but is **really slow** on a real device (iPhone 4GS).

When running the application under "instruments", I see the following call tree:

[image]

Note that the calls within the red circle are reported to take almost all of the CPU time of the method.

The method in question is a class method (not an instance method), with the following code:

```
@implementation Line2F

+ (CGFloat)signTested:(Point2F *)tested p1:(Point2F *)p1 p2:(Point2F *)p2
{
    return [Line2F signTestedX:tested.x testedY:tested.y
                           p1x:p1.x p1y:p1.y
                           p2x:p2.x p2y:p2.y];
}

+ (CGFloat)signTestedX:(CGFloat)testedX testedY:(CGFloat)testedY
                   p1x:(CGFloat)p1x p1y:(CGFloat)p1y
                   p2x:(CGFloat)p2x p2y:(CGFloat)p2y
{
  return (testedX - p2x) * (p1y - p2y) - (p1x - p2x) * (testedY - p2y);  
}

@end
```

Can anyone explain why is most of the CPU time is spent on `[NSObject release]` and `[NSObject retain]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't know any better ARC will retain all the arguments to a method and release them when the method exits (see [this objc-language mailing list email](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2011/Nov/msg00005.html)).

You should be able to avoid this by annotating the arguments to `+signTested:p1:p2:` with either `__weak` or `__unsafe_unretained`, per your needs.

Comment: The issue isn't in `+signTestedX:testedY:p1x:p1y:p2x:p2y:` which takes the CGFloat arguments; as you note floats aren't objects and the semantics there wouldn't make sense. The issue is in `+signTested:p1:p2:` that calls through to `+signTestedX:testedY:p1x:p1y:p2x:p2y:` and takes `Point2F` arguments which (it appears) are objects that _can_ be retained/released.

Comment: passing a __weak directive still has some ARC processing but its faster. The only way I found to completely remove is by just passing CGFloat instead of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Well could be a lot of stuff. As FrozenDevil says it could be related to ARC if you are using it. I imagine that most probably the method is called different times inside a huge loop. Try to pass weak references, but of course you must be sure that they exist for the whole process. I would try also to optimize the loop embedding each cycle in an autorelease pool.